# Building Eclipse SWT on Solaris

Tags: maven, swt, solaris, solaris-10

I've been tasked with build SWT jar files for Solaris. Unfortunately, the prebuilt versions available for Solaris are too old, so I'm left with no other choice.

To start I have very limited experience with Maven, but I've been picking some up as I go.

When I try

```
mvn clean package
```

I get the following:

```
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.tools.base:3.107.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/User/employees/culver_city/giperez/git/eclipse.platform.swt/bundles/org.eclipse.swt.tools.base/pom.xml
[INFO] {osgi.os=linux, osgi.ws=gtk, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.swt.tools.base 3.107.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: org.eclipse.swt 3.107.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86 [3.107.0.qualifier,3.107.0.qualifier]' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.swt.tools.base 3.107.0.qualifier depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.ui 3.4.0
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.ui 3.109.100.v20180426-0903 depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.swt [3.103.0,4.0.0)
```

It is complaining org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86, which does not make sense I'm building for Solaris.

The problem seems to be that:

[INFO] {osgi.os=linux, osgi.ws=gtk, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86}

So OSGI is being passed 'linux' as the OS, which again does not make sense. I figured that if I could fix that, then I should be able to get around this issue, but I haven't been able to.

I have tried adding the following to the root pom.xml:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
<artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
<version>${tycho.version}</version>
<configuration>
<environments>
<environment>
    <os>solaris</os>
    <ws>gtk</ws>
    <arch>x86_64</arch>
</environment>
```

And I have tried many variations:

```
mvn clean package -Dorg.eclipse.osgi.os=solaris
```

Regardless, I see:

```
[INFO] {osgi.os=linux, osgi.ws=gtk, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86}
```

And the same error ensues.

Oddly, if I try:

```
mvn clean package -Pbuild-individual-bundles
```

This works! However, the 'jar' file I'm looking for (org.eclipse.swt.gtk.jar or some variation of that) does not exist.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work on Solaris?

Comment: Well since support for Solaris was dropped in 4.7 I imagine the build tools were updated so they no longer recognize it.